# Replacing CONTROL KEY with COMMAND in MAC for Wine Notepad++

Tags: mac, mojave

Am a fan of notepad++, now am using MAC and installed npp++ with wine.

I want to replace the control key with the command key that way I don't need to brake my Mac commands/shortcuts.

What is the easiest way to get that replaced? I saw something on google which said to use a patched copy of winemacdrive.so. etc or keyboard.c nothing worked(keyboard.c) file itself is not there in my Mac.

Comment: the only way I know is to switch they function but it will be system wide. It is easy to do.

Comment: There are tools which let you change key bindings dependent on what app is in front, is that sufficient? I can write a full answer later

Comment: can you please let me know what to do. ; all I want is notepad++ to work fine in MAC with command c for copy rather than control c

Comment: I tried the app but it doesn't have any integration with wine to adjust the keyboard settings.